# Custom Post Type and Category Base Rewrite Issue

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, url-rewriting

I am having an issue that I have been unable to find a solution to regarding the use of the category base rewrite and a custom post type (projects).

- I am using the Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin to obtain the proper url for my custom post type (projects).

> mydomain.com/projects/category/post-name

This works just fine but when I attempt to rewrite my category base to include "projects" instead of "category" the category url seems to take over and break the custom post type url. The url below is the category base I need.

> mydomain.com/projects/category

I have added this to my functions.php to control the base slug for the cpt.

```
'rewrite' => array(
     'slug' => 'projects'
 ),
```

They just don't play well together and I don't know why. Can anyone lead me to a solution or help explain what the problem is here.

Thanks in advance!